# Clip box-shadow to look like my example

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I was wondering how I can replicate the image below

[image]
[image]
Currently mine looks like the image below

[image]

Is there a way I can clip the `box-shadow` to stay in the bars boundary or another way altogether to achieve this effect?

Here is my css for it:

```
.slider.slider-horizontal {
  width: 100%;
}
.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-track {
  height: 13px;
}
.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-track .slider-track-high {
  background-color: grey;
  background-image: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-track .slider-handle {
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-track .slider-selection {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-image: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Below is my markup:

```
<div class="slider slider-horizontal" id="">
    <div class="slider-track">
        <div class="slider-track-low"></div>
        <div class="slider-selection"></div>
        <div class="slider-track-high"></div>
        <div class="slider-handle min-slider-handle round" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100000" aria-valuenow="3" tabindex="0"></div>
        <div class="slider-handle max-slider-handle round hide" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100000" aria-valuenow="0" tabindex="0"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Slider-handle is the part with the box shadow I am trying to achieve the effect on

**Code bin of my current efforts**

http://codepen.io/Kieranmv95/pen/ZWqBVP

Comment: Can you post your markup as well?

Comment: Better yet, make a Jsbin/Jsfiddle

Comment: added codepen @BikasVaibhav

Comment: You could but that does not look *at all natural*...where is the shadow supposed to be going?

Comment: @Paulie_D the shadow has to look like the first image the second image is my current effort

Comment: No, I get that but the *first image** doesn't look natural.

Comment: In the context it does, give me a second and i will add enw image

Comment: @Paulie_D there you go updated images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting it on slider-handle you can put the `box-shadow` on `.slider-track-high` class, like this-

```
$blueButton:                  #06aeff;
$grey:                        #B3B0BD;

.slider.slider-horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    .slider-track {
        height: 13px;
        .slider-track-high {
            background-color: $grey;
            background-image: none;
            box-shadow: -12px 0 0px #222;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }
        .slider-handle {
            background-color: $blueButton;
            background-image: none;
//            box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px black;
            margin-top: -4px;
        }
        .slider-selection {
            border-radius: 20px;
            background-image: none;
            box-shadow: none;
            background-color: $blueButton;
        }
    }
}
```